# Tag Confusion - infographic information-graphic

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference, which is correct? They both serve the same function; should we blitz one?

Answer (score 4):

I say we should combine them to "infographics."  (Shorter, and while jargon, it's both pleasing-sounding and actually makes sense, a rare combination.)

Comment: It was brought to my attention because @e100 had gone through and added information-graphics to every post tagged infographic and because of the edits they were all on top of each other on the home screen. It should be one or the other. My vote leans with yours - infographic all the way!

Comment: I've added a tag synonym to information-graphics to address this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to retag as information-graphics, by adding the information-graphics tag, then making infographic a synonym of information-graphics; but having not done this before I wasn't aware you needed rep on a tag to create synonyms.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: I can see the synonym is in place, but doesn't seem to be working as I expected, i.e. both sets of tags are still visible on the three questions.

Answer (score 3):

While I caused the problem (see comment on Lauren's answer), I do think **information graphic(s)** is the standard, established term, and **infographic** is a a currently fashionable term which tends to be used for a single page of charts which values presentation/whimsy over meaningful display of data.

See also [Info-graphics , Informative Graphics and Visualizations: Are they the same term ?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98/info-graphics-informative-graphics-and-visualizations-are-they-the-same-term) and particularly the [example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/philgyford/4505748943/) linked to.

Comment: No worries that you created the problem, it's not even a problem as such. The issue has already come up in the question you linked to so it was likely to come up again. And hey, we're still in beta so experimentation is good. +1

Comment: oh no, I've been whimsified! I shall lower my head and slink away in shame. ;) I have no objection to "information graphic" other than that it's long and unwieldy, and long terms are often shortened.

Comment: Done:-) I only learned how to do this tonight, sorry it took me so long... The tag is properly merged, there only exists 1 tag, and information-graphics is the default name.